# How do I get the latest timestamp value for a specific hour per day?

Tags: sql-server, datetime

In a MS SQL Sever DB, I have two fields. A value field, and a timestamp field. I want to get the value for the last timestamp for 2 particular hour(s) for each day. For example, with records like this:

| Value | insert_datetime |
| --- | --- |
| A | 2022-06-07 07:05:16.253 |
| B | 2022-06-07 07:10:16.253 |
| C | 2022-06-07 07:15:16.253 |
| D | 2022-06-07 15:05:16.253 |
| E | 2022-06-07 15:10:16.253 |
| F | 2022-06-07 15:15:16.253 |
| G | 2022-06-07 19:05:16.253 |
| H | 2022-06-07 19:10:16.253 |
| I | 2022-06-07 19:15:16.253 |

I want only the data captured for the latest minute for each 7am and 7pm snapshot:

| Value | insert_datetime |
| --- | --- |
| C | 2022-06-07 07:15:16.253 |
| I | 2022-06-07 19:15:16.253 |

What I've tried for my code:

```
select * from tbl
where DATEPART(hour,[insert_datetime]) in ('07','19')
and DATEPART(minute,[insert_datetime]) in (select max(DATEPART(minute,[insert_datetime])) 
                                           from tbl 
                                           group by [insert_datetime]
                                           )
```

But there seem to have some problem with the way I "group" them, with the error message showing "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'group'" Can any one help me out with this? TIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to find the latest dates for your two hours, you can do following:

```
SELECT MAX(insert_datetime) AS insert_datetime FROM tbl
WHERE DATEPART(HOUR,insert_datetime) IN (7,19)
GROUP BY DATEPART(HOUR,insert_datetime)
```

If you also want to get the value for these dates, you can use the query as subquery:

```
SELECT value, insert_datetime FROM tbl WHERE insert_datetime IN
(SELECT MAX(insert_datetime) AS insert_datetime FROM tbl
WHERE DATEPART(HOUR,insert_datetime) IN (7,19)
GROUP BY DATEPART(HOUR,insert_datetime));
```

If you want to get this information for multiple days, you can extend the sub query and also group by the day:

```
SELECT value, insert_datetime FROM tbl WHERE insert_datetime IN
(SELECT MAX(insert_datetime) AS insert_datetime FROM tbl
WHERE DATEPART(HOUR,insert_datetime) IN (7,19)
GROUP BY DATEPART(HOUR,insert_datetime), 
CAST(insert_datetime AS DATE));
```

If you furthermore need to do a restriction on a certain date range, you can extend the `WHERE` clause. To check the date according to the example of your comment (only taking the last 10 days), this query will work:

```
SELECT value, insert_datetime FROM tbl WHERE insert_datetime IN
(SELECT MAX(insert_datetime) AS insert_datetime FROM tbl
WHERE DATEPART(HOUR,insert_datetime) IN (7,19)
AND DATEDIFF(DAY,insert_datetime,GETDATE()) BETWEEN 0 and 10
GROUP BY DATEPART(HOUR,insert_datetime), 
CAST(insert_datetime AS DATE));
```

Comment: If i am a little bit more greedy here and i want to look at past 10 days data using the subquery method, where do I add in this code:  DATEDIFF(day,[insert_datetime],GETDATE()) between 0 and 10?? Thanks!

Comment: @QYTeng: Edited the answer to show this case.

Comment: Thanks! Code works to be fine! Got some issues sorting out the CAST() function earlier: Code works for CAST([insert_datetime] AS DATE) but not CAST([insert_datetime] AS 'DATE')

Answer (score 1):

Since you're trying to find elements across two windows of time you might have better luck using `row_number()` with partitions, e.g.:

```sql
select
  [Value],
  insert_datetime
from (
  select
    [Value],
    insert_datetime,
    row_number() over (partition by datepart(hour, insert_datetime) order by insert_datetime desc) as [rn]
  from dbo.tbl
  where datepart(hour, insert_datetime) in (7, 19)
) Src
where rn=1;
```

Which yields the output:

| Value | insert_datetime |
| --- | --- |
| C | 2022-06-07 07:15:16.253 |
| I | 2022-06-07 19:15:16.253 |

Comment: I don't know if this is a problem for the OP, but this will not select all values having an identic highest insert_datetime in the range.

Comment: Agreed with Jonas Metzler, i think the code will not be structurally stable to pull out more data point if there is more than 1 data point for the same insert datetime..

Comment: @QYTeng Then just change `ROW_NUMBER` to `DENSE_RANK`